# What steps are needed to make OS X Yosemite use an alternate drive for home directories?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

Immediately after restoring my Mid-2012 MacBook Pro (Retina) to OS X Yosemite 10.10.1, I copied the contents of my home directory to a separate logical partition called "Data" (/Volumes/Data/Username) and changed my home directory path in System Preferences > Users and Groups.  I rebooted as it requires.

Since making this change, I have experienced frequent freezing, most notably when using Safari, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and System Preferences. Coinciding with the freezing, I found constant spamming in system logs like this:

> kernel[0]: Sandbox: fmfd(298) deny file-read-metadata /Volumes/Data

Right or wrong, in fmfd.sb, under allow file-read-metadata, I have added:
       (literal "/Volumes/Data")

Rebooted and now the system is not freezing and the errors in the logs have stopped.

Is the fix of allowing read permissions to this volume appropriate/safe?  Are there are any other issues using a home directory on a separate volume?

Comment: Having the same issue! As an old UNIX hacker, that's always the first thing I do on a new system, is put all users on a separate partition. But I guess Apple Knows Better™.